# How to serialize a class that extends TreeSet with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Class A looks like this:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class A extends TreeSet<B> {

    private final a;
    private b;
    private c;

    public A(a, b, c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public final class B  {
    private final int x;
    private final double y;
}
```

When I serialize a class A object using Jackson:

```
jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(class_a_object);
```

I get a json Array like this:

```
[
  {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 3.23
  },
  {
    "x": 4,
    "y": 2.12
  },...
]
```

but the member variables a,b,c are missing. Is there a way I can include them into the json string?

Comment: Where would you like them to appear? What would your ideal output JSON look like?

Comment: I want them to appear before the array.

Comment: That's not very clear. Jackson produces JSON so it must be valid. You could change your `A` class to have a `TreeSet` field instead of subclassing `TreeSet`. Then Jackson would produce a JSON object with each of your 3 fields. The `TreetSet` field would be your JSON array like you have in your question.

Comment: All Java collection types are handled in a special way: maps, sets, lists. For sets and lists, Jackson just gets an iterator and writes out its elements within a JSON array.

Comment: I am not allowed to remove the inheritance. Is there no other way to get the same output as with the TreeSet field?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this by writing a custom serializer but I can't remember if there's a way to register it before the ones handling the collection types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jackson` recognises class `A` as a collection and register `CollectionSerializer` to serialise `A`'s instances. We can modify default serialiser and provide custom serialiser. We can use `BeanSerializerModifier` to do that and reuse collection serialiser in custom implementation. To generate valid `JSON` you need to provide property name for set values.

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ModifyCollectionSerializerApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        A a = new A(1, 2);
        a.add(new B(22, 2.2));
        a.add(new B(33, 3.3));

        SimpleModule aModule = new SimpleModule();
        aModule.setSerializerModifier(new ABeanSerializerModifier());
        JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .addModule(aModule)
                .build();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(a);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}

class ABeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifyCollectionSerializer(SerializationConfig config, CollectionType valueType, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        return new AJsonSerializer(serializer);
    }
}

class AJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {

    private final JsonSerializer valuesSerializer;

    AJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer valuesSerializer) {
        this.valuesSerializer = valuesSerializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField("a", value.getA());
        gen.writeNumberField("b", value.getB());
        gen.writeFieldName("values");
        valuesSerializer.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class A extends TreeSet<B> {

    private final int a;
    private final int b;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
class B implements Comparable<B> {
    private final int x;
    private final double y;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(B o) {
        return this.x - o.x;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "values" : [ {
    "x" : 22,
    "y" : 2.2
  }, {
    "x" : 33,
    "y" : 3.3
  } ]
}
```